# How do I stop a moving object when colliding with a static wall or falling to a static ground

Tags: c++, collision-detection, physics, sdl2

I'm writing my very first 2D game engine in C++ and SDL2. I wrote a very simplistic `RigidBody` class that computes the resultant force, applies forces and simulates gravity. I also wrote a `BoxCollider` class and a `QuadTree` class which as any game dev would know manages collisions. Every thing seems to be working fine, however I'm facing a pit stop I can't wrap my head around. How do I stop a `GameObject` when it collides with a static wall or ground. I tried setting the `velocity` to zero but that literally freezes the object and I can't move it using my controls. Also setting the `gravity` to zero doesn't stop the object since it still has a non zero `velocity` and it sort of digs it's way through the ground. How can I implement this and if there are any decent tutorials regarding my question please do share them. Thanks!

Comment: The term you want to search for here is [tag:collision-resolution]. Usually you'll do something like computing the time of impact or penetration depth of one collider into another, and generate impulses to apply to dynamic bodies in the collision to separate them.

Answer (score 1):

Check out Erin Catto’s (one of the creators of Box2D) [GDC slides](https://github.com/erincatto/box2d-lite/blob/master/docs/GDC2006_Catto_Erin_PhysicsTutorial.pdf), he has by far one of the most succinct explanations of collision resolutions i’ve ever read. He also provides an accompanying [demo of code](https://github.com/erincatto/box2d-lite) which actually implements incredibly straight forward collision resolution in just a few hundred lines of code. He uses what is known as a sequential impulse solver, which is mathematically very similar to gauss-siedel solvers (a very common MLCP solver used in game physics).

Comment: Thanks, I will check it out!